# PHP find all combinations to a sum in inner array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a PHP script for available rooms in a hotel. I want every combination for a group (i.e. 4 person). This is my array.

```
$room_array = array(
    array(
        "title"         => "1 person room",
        "room_for"      => 1,
        "price"         => 79
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "2 person room with other",
        "room_for"      => 1,
        "price"         => 69
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "2 person room alone",
        "room_for"      => 1, 
        "price"         => 89
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "2 person",
        "room_for"      => 2,
        "price"         => 69
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "3 person",
        "room_for"      => 3,
        "price"         => 69
    )
);
```

Possible outcome:

- 4x 1 person room
- 4x 2 person room with other
- 3x 1 person room + 1x 2 person room with other
- 2x 2 person room
- 1x 3 person room + 1x 1 person room

etc. etc.

This calls for a recursive function. But every example I looked at doesn't work with counting in the inner array. The closest i found was this question:

[Finding potential combinations of numbers for a sum (given a number set to select from)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453414/finding-potential-combinations-of-numbers-for-a-sum-given-a-number-set-to-selec)

But i didn't get de solution to work..

**UPDATE:**

Hi, thanks for all the answers. Really helped me in finding the best practice. In the meantime, the assignment has changed a little so I can't answer my own original question. My problem is solved. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If you get rid of the array structure and look to Objects or Nodes, you can use Dijkstra's algorithm and change it a bit to suit your needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "with other"? That the total can actually be more than four, as long as everyone gets a room?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838330/3600709) answer to get all combinations, change the functionality to return you the array key instead of the number of guests.

Comment: @Don'tPanic "with other" means that you share the room with someone 'strange'. You do not know who your roommate is.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

My answer below will get you partway there.

---

### Resources

I borrowed some code logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838330/3600709) answer.
To quote the answer (in case of future removal), please view below.

> You can try
>
> ```
> echo "<pre>";
> $sum = 12 ; //SUM
> $array = array(6,1,3,11,2,5,12);
> $list = array();
> # Extract All Unique Conbinations
> extractList($array, $list);
> #Filter By SUM = $sum     $list =
> array_filter($list,function($var) use ($sum) { return(array_sum($var) == $sum);});
> #Return Output
> var_dump($list);
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> array
>   0 => array
>     1 => string '1' (length=1)
>     2 => string '2' (length=1)
>     3 => string '3' (length=1)
>     4 => string '6' (length=1)
>   1 => array
>     1 => string '1' (length=1)
>     2 => string '5' (length=1)
>     3 => string '6' (length=1)
>   2 => array
>     1 => string '1' (length=1)
>     2 => string '11' (length=2)
>   3 => array
>     1 => string '12' (length=2)
> ```
>
> Functions Used
>
> ```
> function extractList($array, &$list, $temp = array()) {
>     if(count($temp) > 0 && ! in_array($temp, $list))
>         $list[] = $temp;
>     for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i ++) {
>         $copy = $array;
>         $elem = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);
>         if (sizeof($copy) > 0) {
>             $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
>             sort($add);
>             extractList($copy, $list, $add);
>         } else {
>             $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
>             sort($add);
>             if (! in_array($temp, $list)) {
>                 $list[] = $add;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

---

### My answer

The code below uses the code referenced above. I changed the return functionality of the `array_filter` function to map it to your needs.

The only thing left for you to do is change the function so that it can catch multiple of the same type of room. At the moment, the code below will only output 1 of each type of room (as per the code referenced above). An easy way to get around this would be to multiply the array values you send to the function by the number of guests you are searching for rooms, but up to the amount of rooms available. So: if you are looking to book for 4 guests and you have no single rooms remaining and only 1 double room, your *best match* result would have to be a `2 person room` and a `3 person room`. I've added some *brief* functionality to add this (it's commented out), although I have not tested it. It will likely take a while to process that as well so if you're looking for a quicker method, you're gonna have to use a better algorithm as already mentioned in previous comments/answers or solve [P vs NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)

The code below also gives you the option to toggle a value of `$exact`. This value, if set to `true`, will return only matches **exactly equal to the number of guests**, and if set to `false` will return all matches that **equal to at least the number of guests**.

```
<?php

class Booking {
    private $minGuests = 1;
    protected $guests = 1;
    protected $rooms = [];

    public function getRoomCombinations(bool $exact = true) {
        $guests = $this->guests;
        $list = [];
        $rooms = $this->rooms;

        /*for($i = 0; $i < $guests-1; $i++) {
            $rooms = array_merge($rooms, $this->rooms);
        }
        asort($rooms);*/
        $this->extractList($rooms, $list);

        $result = array_filter($list, function($var) use ($guests, $exact) {
            if($exact)
                return(array_sum(array_map(function($item) { return $item['room_for'];}, $var)) == $guests);
            else
                return(array_sum(array_map(function($item) { return $item['room_for'];}, $var)) >= $guests && count($var) <= $guests);
        });
        array_multisort(array_map('count', $result), SORT_ASC, $result);

        return $result;
    }

    private function extractList(array $array, array &$list, array $temp = []) {
        if (count($temp) > 0 && !in_array($temp, $list))
            $list[] = $temp;
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
            $copy = $array;
            $elem = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);
            if (sizeof($copy) > 0) {
                $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
                sort($add);
                $this->extractList($copy, $list, $add);
            } else {
                $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
                sort($add);
                if (!in_array($temp, $list)) {
                    $list[] = $add;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function setGuests(int $guests) {
        $this->guests = ($guests >= $this->minGuests ? $guests : $this->minGuests);
        return $this;
    }

    public function setHotelRooms(array $rooms) {
        $this->rooms = $rooms;
        return $this;
    }
}

$booking = (new Booking())
    ->setGuests(4)
    ->setHotelRooms([
        [
            "title"         => "1 person room",
            "room_for"      => 1,
            "price"         => 79
        ],
        [
            "title"         => "2 person room with other",
            "room_for"      => 1,
            "price"         => 69
        ],
        [
            "title"         => "2 person room alone",
            "room_for"      => 1, 
            "price"         => 89
        ],
        [
            "title"         => "2 person",
            "room_for"      => 2,
            "price"         => 69
        ],
        [
            "title"         => "3 person",
            "room_for"      => 3,
            "price"         => 69
        ]
    ]);
echo '<pre>' . var_export($booking->getRoomCombinations(true), true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the combinations then you can use an backtracking iterative algorithm (depth path).

In summary:

1. Type of tree: binary tree because all the levels can contain a solution when the number of persons contabilized = objetive

   [Binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjY5s.png)
2. Algorithm functions
   You need to increment the cont every time that a level is generated with the number of persons of the level and decrement when you change your track (exploring brothers or back)

solution: array[0..levels-1] values {0 (node not selected) ,1 (node selected)}

solution[0] = 1 -> You choose that "1 person room" belongs to the solution

solutions: list/array of objects and every object contains array of titles of rooms

```
function Backtracking ()
    level:= 1
    solution:= s_initial
    end:= false
    repeat
         generate(level, solution)
         IF solution(level, solution) then
           save_solution
         else if test(level, solution) then
            level:= level+ 1
         else
            while NOT MoreBrothers(level, solution)
               go_back(level, s)

    until level==0
```

2.1. Generate: generate next node

2.2. Solution: test if it's a solution

2.3. Critery: if we must continue by this track or bound

2.4. MoreBrothers: if there are nodes without check at this level

2.5. Backtrack: all the nodes at this level were explored

2.6. Save solution: add to the solutions array your object that contains strings

Comment: Sounds like the OP is looking for a solution written in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```php
$room_array = array(
    array(
        "title"         => "1 person room",
        "room_for"      => 1,
        "price"         => 79
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "2 person room with other",
        "room_for"      => 1,
        "price"         => 69
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "2 person room alone",
        "room_for"      => 1,
        "price"         => 89
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "2 person",
        "room_for"      => 2,
        "price"         => 69
    ),
    array(
        "title"         => "3 person",
        "room_for"      => 3,
        "price"         => 69
    )
);

// Gets rooms based on a given number of guests
function get_possible_rooms($num_guests) {
    global $room_array;
    $possible_rooms = [];

    foreach ($room_array as $room) {
        if ($num_guests <= $room['room_for']) {
            $possible_rooms[] = $room['title'];
        }
    }

    return $possible_rooms;
}

// Gets the available room capacities
function get_room_capacities() {
    global $room_array;
    $capacities = [];

    foreach ($room_array as $room) {
        $capacities[] = $room['room_for'];
    }

    return array_unique($capacities);
}

// Gets the different combinations of groups of guests based on the room capacities
function get_guest_assignments($remaining_guests, $parent_id = '', $num_guests, &$result) {
    $room_capacities = get_room_capacities();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $remaining_guests; ++$i) {
        if (in_array($i, $room_capacities)) {
            $parent_guests = (isset($result[$parent_id])) ? $result[$parent_id] : 0;
            $result[$parent_id . $i] = $parent_guests + $i;

            for ($j = 1; $j <= $remaining_guests - $i; ++$j) {
                // Recursively get the results for children
                get_guest_assignments($j, $parent_id . $i, $num_guests, $result);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($remaining_guests === 1 && $parent_id !== '') {
        // If it reaches the end and it does not fulfill the required number of guests,
        // mark it for removal later
        if ($result[$parent_id] < $num_guests) {
            $result[$parent_id] = null;
        }
    }

    // This is the last recursion
    if ($result[$parent_id . '1'] === $num_guests) {
        // Remove duplicates. 
        // To do this, we need to re-sort the keys (e.g. 21 becomes 12) and call array_unique()
        // I admit this is a bit sloppy implementation.
        $combinations = [];

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if ($value !== null) {
                $nums = str_split($key);
                sort($nums);
                $combinations[] = implode('', $nums);
            }
        }

        $result = array_unique($combinations);
    }
}

// Gets the rooms for each group of guest
function get_room_assignments($guest_str) {
    $rooms = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($guest_str); ++$i) {
        $num_guests = intval(substr($guest_str, $i, 1));
        $rooms[] = get_possible_rooms($num_guests);
    }

    return $rooms;
}

//----------
// RUN
//----------

$guests = 4;
$result = [];

get_guest_assignments($guests, null, $guests, $result);

foreach ($result as $guest_combi) {
    $assignments = get_room_assignments($guest_combi);

    // Printing output
    echo 'Guest Combination ' . $guest_combi . "\n";
    echo json_encode($assignments, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

The output will look something like this:

```
...
Guest Combination 13
[
    [
        "1 person room",
        "2 person room with other",
        "2 person room alone",
        "2 person",
        "3 person"
    ],
    [
        "3 person"
    ]
]
...
```

"Guest combination 13" means the 4 guests will be split into groups of 1 and 3 persons.

Output is an array of possible rooms for each group. So in the example, the **group of 1** can book 1 person room, 2 person room with other, ... 3 person room. And the **group of 3** can book 3 person room.

—

Other notes:

- I know we hate `global` but doing this just for brevity. Feel free to modify.
- There's a shorter way to code this, but this implementation makes it easier to debug since guest combinations are used as keys.